# Changing Text of EditText With a Little Animation in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am making a simple calculator application for android. I've already made the code and everything works fine. However, I want to improve the design of its user interface by adding a little animation for the changing of text. So it's like this for example:

1. I will enter input via the buttons to the edittext, say for example, "2+3".
2. When I will press the enter button, "2+3" moves up and disappears then "5", from below, replaces the original position of "2+3".

How can I do this?

Comment: Check out this site https://android-arsenal.com/tag/101, see if any of the solutions available there helps you.

Comment: @55597 I'm sorry sir. I tried to scan over for the solution in that site but I didn't see the correct one. But still, thank you for the effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should answer your question now that I understand it a little better. You just need a couple of animation files, one to slide the text out, and one to slide it in. You can adjust the animations however you would like:

Here is your click listener for the equals button:

```
    Button btnEquals = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEquals);
        btnEquals.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Animation slideOutBottom = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.out_bottom);
                slideOutBottom.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
// Update the text here
                        Animation slideInTop = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.in_top);
                        llContainer.startAnimation(slideInTop);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });

                llContainer.startAnimation(slideOutBottom);

            }
        });
    }
```

And here are the out_bottom.xml and in_top.xml files (respectively) that go in your anim folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="100%" android:duration="600"/>
</set>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="-100%" android:toYDelta="0%" android:duration="600"/>
</set>
```

And here is how I wrapped the layouts. Kind of quick and dirty, but it works:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="#fff">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtInput"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:background="@null"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEquals"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="="/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: sir, I tried to implement the methods of your solution and it indeed worked. However, it did not answer my problem because when I call collapse, the whole edittext collapses and not just the text within. And same as expand, the whole edittext expands and not just the text

Comment: As far as I know you can't collapse text, only the container of the text. But if you wrap the EditText in a fixed-height container, it should give the illusion that the text is being moved. I have a working example, I will update my answer.

Comment: sir, can you summarize all the steps please? sorry very much if I am annoying you but I didn't quite get everything. So please? Like 1. create xml file then name it out_bottom. 2.create the second xml file bla bla. Please? :D

Comment: Here's a quick rundown of the steps 
1. Create the directory res/anim if it doesn't already exist.
2. Create the out_bottom.xml file in the anim directory.
3. Create the in_top.xml file in the anim directory.
4. Add the LinearLayout container to your layout as outlined in activity_main
5. Set the click listener for the equals button as outlined in the Activity.